# iPhone: Video recording using any other way apart from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone

Please help on this, its very crazy, not working at all.
Due to the query from the following link, i couldn't resolve the video recorder automatic stop by using setVideoMaximumDuration issue at all for almost 2 weeks on iOS 4.3 iPad 2.

[iPhone:Strange Issue with videoMaximumDuration property in Video recorder API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620475/iphonestrange-issue-with-videomaximumduration-property-in-video-recorder-api)

I would like to know, is there any other way apart from using UIImagePickerController, to record video with the time set programmatically.

Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check out AVFoundation. Some great video from [WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).